# How can i use geofencing using Estimote IOS SDk

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am working with Estimote beacon for my iOS application.

How can I implement Geo fencing along with Beacons?

Comment: What is Your doubt based on? Did You search google and found too little information how to do it, or found no examples? Please provide some more insight and tell us what Have You tried?

Comment: +20 am looking for this

Answer (score 1):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a cmmunity evangelist at Estimote.

At this point , Estimote SDK does not provide ready solutions for geofencing. But you should try playing around with Region Monitoring and Ranging. the first of this methods is used to detect whether the receiving device is in the vicinity of a Beacon or not, and works in the background mode. Ranging, on the other hand, is used to approximate the distance between a Beacon and the receiver. You need an app to go into foreground to enable ranging.